# English word for so consumed in thought you fail to hear

Tags: nouns, adjectives

For example, someone is going to the mall, and he's so set on getting to the mall that when you call him he does not hear you.

Comment: In the US, most girls call them "boyfriends".

Comment: There are plenty of words like *busy, preoccupied, absorbed, distracted, engrossed,...* But I seriously doubt English will have a specific term for (involuntary) failure to hear on account of being otherwise engaged. For the *voluntary* context, there's ***selective deafness***.

Answer (score 3):

I think you may use ***absorbed***:

To absorb:

> - To occupy the attention, interest, or time of; engross: *The problem completely absorbed her.*

The Free Dictionary

- he was too absorbed in his thoughts to hear me,

Answer (score 0):

Consider [***lost in thought:***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/lost-in-thought)

> Concentrating on or pondering over something. For example, *Gwen didn't hear a word you said; she was lost in thought*

Or you may prefer [***wrapped-up:***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/wrapped--up)

> **20.a :** intensely absorbed in: *wrapped up in one's work*